# How to create with column picture in list Sharepoint Fundation

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, column, picture

I'd like to ask you how I can create column with picture in SP list? I imported Excel datasheet with use web part and now I have several hundred line in list and I want to add new column with picture but not with hiperlink?

How I can do it?

Comment: You mean that you want, for example, upload image from your local drive?

Comment: Yes, I have list with line and I would like add column with picture which add from local drive...

Answer (score 1):

there is an codeplex solution which let you create a column based on a new custom fieldtype:
http://sps2010imagefld.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

use a sharepoint document library and upload image and use sp object model to fetch the images through code

Comment: Could you be so kind and tell me how I can do it? Thanks for your support